# Need PPM out of MQ4 sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, sensors

I'm using this working library to extract H2 & Alcohol in PPM from sensors.

UPDATE
I read the readme file and used the example shown.
But this gives me an error.

This is the code:

```
  //Include the library
#include <MQUnifiedsensor.h>
/************************Hardware Related Macros************************************/
#define         Board                   ("Arduino UNO")
#define         Pin                     (A4)  //Analog input 4 of your arduino
/***********************Software Related Macros************************************/
#define         Type                    ("MQ-4") //MQ4
#define         Voltage_Resolution      (5)
#define         ADC_Bit_Resolution      (10) // For arduino UNO/MEGA/NANO
#define         RatioMQ4CleanAir        (4.4) //RS / R0 = 60 ppm 
/*****************************Globals***********************************************/
//Declare Sensor
MQUnifiedsensor MQ4(Board, Voltage_Resolution, ADC_Bit_Resolution, Pin, Type);
// Setup
MQ4.setRegressionMethod("Exponential"); //_PPM =  a*ratio^b
MQ4.setA(1012.7); MQ4.setB(-2.786); // Configurate the ecuation values to get CH4 concentration
MQ4.setR0(3.86018237); // Value getted on calibration
// Loop
MQ4.init();
MQ4.update();
float ppmCH4 = MQ4.readSensor();
```

And the error:

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Mac OS X), Board: "WeMos D1 R1, 80 MHz, Flash, Legacy (new can return nullptr), All SSL ciphers (most compatible), 4MB (FS:2MB OTA:~1019KB), v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 921600"

MQ4:17:1: error: 'MQ4' does not name a type
MQ4.setRegressionMethod("Exponential"); //_PPM =  a*ratio^b
^
MQ4:18:1: error: 'MQ4' does not name a type
MQ4.setA(1012.7); MQ4.setB(-2.786); // Configurate the ecuation values to get CH4 concentration
^
MQ4:18:19: error: 'MQ4' does not name a type
MQ4.setA(1012.7); MQ4.setB(-2.786); // Configurate the ecuation values to get CH4 concentration
^
MQ4:19:1: error: 'MQ4' does not name a type
MQ4.setR0(3.86018237); // Value getted on calibration
^
MQ4:21:1: error: 'MQ4' does not name a type
MQ4.init();
^
MQ4:22:1: error: 'MQ4' does not name a type
MQ4.update();
^
exit status 1
'MQ4' does not name a type

Comment: please describe the `I tried several things`

Comment: You understand that if the library doesn't do what you need, you can make your own copy of it and modify it, right?

Comment: The function `serialDebug()` is only for debug, as the name says. When you need a specific value, the  library also provides functions for that. Have you ever tried looking at the readme of the library. There you can find the line `float ppmCH4 = MQ4.readSensor()`. Seems to be what you want

Comment: @chrisl I looked and used the example from the readme but it gives me the error I wrote in the updated question.

Comment: You need to write a real code with the functions `setup()` and `loop()`. It isn't enough to write a comment with these names. You cannot execute any functions at global scope (outside of any other function).

Comment: @chrisl thanks for the help. But I figured out what the origin of the problem was. There where library issues reinstall of all did the trick! Thanks for the help though! :)